# Terraform : AWS Redshift IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Im trying to setup a redshift cluster and an IAM role that will have access to the cluster. I am using terraform for this. According the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-create-an-iam-role.html) I need to create a Service role and attach the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy to it. I have the following config in my terraform script:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_admin_role" {
  name = "my-role"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*",
        "redshift:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

However this gives me an error:

Errors:

```
  * aws_iam_role.my_admin_role: "assume_role_policy": required field is not set
  * aws_iam_role.my_admin_role: : invalid or unknown key: policy
```

How do I setup a service role for redshift ?

Answer (score 0):

You mix the resources `aws_iam_role` and `aws_iam_role_policy`

Sample usage of resource `aws_iam_role`

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Sample usage of resource `aws_iam_role_policy`

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "test_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```